# JavaScript selecting Object Arraylike?

Tags: javascript, json, object

The Problem is the following:
I have a JSON file that has objects with the following name: `"item0": { ... }, "item1": { ... }, "item2": { ... }`. But I can't access them when going through an if method.

What I've done so far:

```
$.getJSON('/assets/storage/items.json', function(data) {
    jsonStringify = JSON.stringify(data);
    jsonFile = JSON.parse(jsonStringify);

    addItems();
});

var addItems = function() {
    /* var declarations */

    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(jsonFile).length; i++) {
        path = 'jsonFile.item' + i;
        name = path.name;
        console.log(path.name);
        console.log(path.type);
    }

}
```

If I console.log path.name it returns undefined. But if I enter jsonFile.item0.name it returns the value. So how can I use the string path so that it's treated like an object, or is there an other way on how to name the json items.

Comment: `path` is a String.

Comment: Why are you parsing and stringifying successively?

Comment: the syntax you're looking for is `jsonFile['item' + i]`

Comment: `var path = 'item'+i; name = jsonFile[path];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: var names like `jsonFile` hurt your thinking. JSON is always a string, and can _never_ be anything else. `jsonFile` is an object, so just name it `file`.

Comment: I would stringify `jsonFile` and then parse it. Just to be sure... (kidding).

Answer (score 1):

As others stated `'jsonFile.item' + i` is not retrieving anything from `jsonFile`: it is just a string.

Other issues:

- It makes no sense to first stringify the data and then parse it again. That is moving back and forth to end up where you already were: `data` is the object you want to work with
- Don't name your data `jsonFile`. It is an object, not JSON. JSON is text. But because of the above remark, you don't need this variable
- Declare your variables with `var`, `let` or `const`, and avoid global variables.
- Use the promise-like syntax (`$.getJSON( ).then`)
- Iterate object properties without assuming they are called `item0`, `item1`,...

Suggested code:

```
$.getJSON('/assets/storage/items.json').then(function(data) {
    for (const path in data) {
        console.log(data[path].name, data[path].type);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use object notation using a dynamic string value as a key instead of an object key. So, instead of using something like `object.dynamicName` you either have use `object[dynamicName]`.

So in your example it would be like this.

```
path = 'item' + i;
jsonFile[path].name
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cannot expect a string to behave like an object.

What you can do is this:

```
path = `item${i}`
name = jsonFile[path].name
```